# Should I do residual analysis on the dev or the train set?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, linear-model, residuals, endogeneity

I have a linear regression model which its only task is prediction, not inference.

I'm making an analysis to check a few assumptions of the linear regression model I created are attended, such as no endogeneity by checking the relationship of the independent variables with the error term, and linearity itself, by checking the residual vs fitted values.

My question is if I should perform this analysis on my train or my dev set?

I've searched all over the internet for this disclaimer but I couldn't find any.

Can someone clarify this to me and also explain why?